# Is it possible to record audio and play a video simultaneously?

Tags: ios, audio-recording

Is it possible to record audio and play a video simultaneously?

I wish to play a video and record the audio around the iPhone. Currently, once the video starts playing, audio recording stops.

Comment: I am not sure that is it possible or not but generally you need to define to players in your code one for playing video and another one for recording audio

Comment: I have players for both these operations. But is it possible simultaneously? If yes the using which players?

Comment: I don't know it's possible or not But try it with two different players maybe that helps you